# python remove duplicated data list in the same ' ' marks

Tags: python, list, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import zip_longest



headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'
}


amazn = requests.get("https://a.co/d/cTzyJwv",headers=headers)

amazn_src = amazn.content

soup =BeautifulSoup(amazn_src,"lxml")

gpu_s3r = soup.find_all("span",{"class":"a-price aok-align-center reinventPricePriceToPayMargin priceToPay"})

gpu_s3r_ap =[]
for i in range(len(gpu_s3r)):
     gpu_s3r_ap.append(gpu_s3r[i].text)
```

the output  is ['$389.00$389.00']

how i can make the gpu_s3r_ap making  ['$389.00'] only this output

i mean how i can make it not duplicated

Comment: You're fetching them all in a loop and combining them.  If that's not what you want, then don't use a loop.

Comment: Please read [SO's guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the nested Span class, just add this line and use find()

```
gpu_s3r = gpu_s3r.find("span",{"class":"a-offscreen"})
```

full code

```
gpu_s3r = soup.find("span",{"class":"a-price aok-align-center 
reinventPricePriceToPayMargin priceToPay"})
gpu_s3r = gpu_s3r.find("span",{"class":"a-offscreen"})
gpu_s3r_ap =[]
gpu_s3r_ap.append(gpu_s3r.text)
print(gpu_s3r_ap)
```

output

```
['$389.61']
```

Answer (score 1):

Improve your selector:

```
[...]
for i in range(len(gpu_s3r)):
     gpu_s3r_ap.append(gpu_s3r[i].select_one('span[class="a-offscreen"]').text)
```

BeautifulSoup documentation: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/